# Does Visa validity period of US refers to duration of stay?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

This question might be dumb,due to unofficial sources asking over here at this community

Recently one of my friend got business visa[H1/B1] with a validity period of 10 years,does that period means he can stay until the visa gets out of date?

```
VISA TYPE/CLASS : R H1/B1
```

For instance his visa validity period was from 1/1/2015 to 1/1/2025,does this mean he can stay upto 2025 in US?

is both are same?if not where he needs to reapply for the period of stay/duration of stay

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: H1 and B1 are quite different things though. One is an immigrant visa, one a non-immigrant visa.

Comment: @CMaster under visa type it has been mentioned as R and H1/B1 let me know any other info related to his visa i will update over here

Comment: Is your friend a citizen of Chile or Singapore? They have special H-1B1 visas available to them.

Comment: "R" means the visa was placed in a regular passport. It can be ignored.

Comment: @CMaster: Both are nonimmigrant visas. An "immigrant visa" is one that immediately makes you a permanent resident upon entry.

Comment: Maybe it says "H1B1"? That's a type of visa for Chilean or Singaporean nationals.

Comment: @mkennedy nope he is indian citizen

Comment: @chx in his visa it was printed as H1/B1 if requires can i upload his visa image for clarifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The validity dates of a US visa work differently](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/visa-expiration-date.html) than in some other countries.

For a US visa, these dates specify the dates which you can arrive at a US port of entry. It does not specify when you must depart.

You can remain beyond the visa expiration date, as long as you remain in status.

For short-term admissions such as tourism and business visits, and for certain work visas, your admittance stamp you receive at the border will show the date you must depart. This is typically six months for short-term admissions, but may be shorter or longer depending on what you told the immigration officer and your visa class.

[image: US B1 admission stamp]
Public domain image provided by [US Embassy Manila](http://blogs.usembassy.gov/philippines/length-of-stay-in-the-united-states/comment-page-1/)

For long-term admissions such as student visas, instead of an expiration date you might see "D/S" which means "duration of status". If D/S appears on your stamp, you need to follow the rules for duration of stay associated with your class of visa (e.g. leaving the US when you are no longer working or studying). In general, when your status ends, you must depart the US.

[image: US F1 admission stamp]
Image provided by [San Francisco State University Office of International Programs](http://oip.sfsu.edu/f1/current/maintain/f1docs)

Comment: Essentially only people in F or J status get "D/S". People on various work visas get a fixed period of stay, depending on the particular status, and usually up to the expiration of their petition for those statuses that require a petition.